# PHP is looking for a file in the wrong place

Tags: php, file, path, directory

I am an amateur web developer and I am trying to get my site live for the first time. The site is working and all of the files are uploaded but the site is not loading my PHP includes.

Here is the error message:

> Warning: include(includes/header.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home4/*myUsername*/public_html/index.php on line 3

How can I get PHP to look in `public_html/` rather than `public_html/index.php`?

EDIT: I have tried editing the include path. It doesn't seem to change where php is looking for the file. Additionally my includes work properly in localhost.

Comment: That means you're not giving the right path to `include()`, we need **code plz**...

Comment: use relative paths for easier deployment

Comment: i have tried editing the include path already (sorry, should have had this in my question). It doesn't seem to change where php is looking for the file. Additionally my includes work properly in localhost.

Comment: try changing the path to: "require_once('./includes/header.php')"

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume this is your folder structure:

- public_html/index.php
- public_html/includes/header.php

Generally (not always), $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] will now reflect the path to the base public_html directory (this I'm assuming based on the context of your message).  This means you can always point to the root this way. - no matter if you have /index.php or /my/deep/file/structure.php

Try this with your include statement on index.php

```
<?php
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/header.php');
```

Answer (score 1):

You may need to change the include path in your php.ini file or use `set_include_path()` to change the include path.

Here is the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php) entry for the function call if you'd like to read more about it.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've found the include path in the php.ini file. What directory should this be set to in this case?

Comment: This is what I'm looking at by the way:

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Paths and Directories ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; UNIX: "/path1:/path2"
;include_path = ".:/php/includes"
;
; Windows: "\path1;\path2"
;include_path = ".;c:\php\includes"
;
; PHP's default setting for include_path is ".;/path/to/php/pear"
; http://php.net/include-path

Comment: You would set it to whatever you needed, the location of the PHP files you are intending to include. This changes the base path of the include, in other words it'll append the path in the `include()` call to whatever you set as the include path here.

Comment: Okay, I've tried this but it is not changing the error message. Thanks for your help but it would seem as though this is a different problem or else I'm not able to properly explain what's happening.

Comment: Is your header.php file actually in the includes directory?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked already the include file?

in given. include(folder_includes/file_header.php);